# MVC Infinite Scrolling in middle column only

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, infinite-scroll

I have a simple MVC5 page with 3 columns (something that look like as Facebook)

[image]

an I would like to code the infinite scrolling only on the middle column, while keeping the other 2 external columns fixed.

QUESTION:
Is is possible to have Columns 2 that keeps scrolling and showing new data while keeping column 1 and 3 fixed in MVC and Razor?

Before people ask me what I have done so far, I want to say that I have no idea where to start and that's why I was hoping to get some directions here.

Comment: Probably a better fit on programmers. As is, this question doesn't fit well here for multiple reasons and will more than likely not hold up well.

Comment: What do you mean by "fit better on programmers" ?

Comment: I think Travis says `http://programmers.stackexchange.com/`

Comment: @SD Developer - On the programmers exchange (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). The answer is yes. However, this is overly broad, there are many different ways to do this and demonstrating one would be asking too much. This is opinion based, as to whether to preload, page, or implement an infinite scroll. This is unclear in that there is no defined problem being solved. This question could also be solved by a parallax library. It does not fit at SO.

Comment: OK ..never heard about that. So just for my understanding, what's the difference between programmers.stackexchange and the main stackoverflow ?

Comment: Got it..okis, I'll move it to the programmers. Thanks !!

Comment: @SDDeveloper - SO is mainly for problems with actual implementation. Programmers is a better fit for design and architecture.